# Error in installing "StatPlots" in Windows for Julia

Tags: julia

I tried several times to Install `StatPlots` pkg using:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("StatPlots")
```

but I got kind of error as mentioned right down bellow:
[image]

How can i install it?
I'm Using `Julia 1.7.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely thinking of [`StatsPlots`](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/StatsPlots.jl) (note the spelling difference)

Comment: Trust me i checked the spelling many times. Thats the name that have been used in one of the ("courseras")[https://www.coursera.org/learn/julia-programming/home/welcome] courses.

Comment: Check [this](https://juliahub.com/ui/Packages/StatPlots/iAmZm/0.9.2) out. Seems there's a package with this name too.

Comment: Hmm, that may be a typo in JuliaHub since the URL for that `StatPlots` page in JuliaHub still points to https://github.com/JuliaPlots/StatsPlots.jl